# Decrypting a JWE token using JOSE with A256GCM

Tags: c#, encryption, jwe, jose

I'm curious about this and wanted to see if anyone understands it.

I am encoding a payload using the `jose-jwt` nuget in .NET:

```
Jose.JWT.Encode(
    payload, 
    keyBytes, 
    JweAlgorithm.A256GCMKW, 
    JweEncryption.A256GCM, 
    extraHeaders: extraHeaders)
```

and this returns a token that looks correct.

When I use JOSE to decrypt the same payload:

```
Jose.JWT.Decode(payload, keyBytes, JweAlgorithm.A256GCMKW, JweEncryption.A256GCM);
```

It throws an error:

> BCrypt.BCryptDecrypt(): authentication tag mismatch

Is this normal? Is the JWE encryption supposed to be unable to be decrypted or can someone explain why this error is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Are you encoding with the public key and decoding with the private key?

Comment: Yes.  The decrypt method is giving an exception due to the data not being encrypted in the same method that is being used to decrypt.

Comment: Is it possible to have sample jwe generated by jose-jwt and associated keys?

Comment: AesGcmKeyWrapManagement management algorithm expected key of size 256 bits. I think you are using a Symmetric key. Check the source code https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt/blob/master/jose-jwt/JWT.cs